# right bracket in my TeXworks does not work

Tags: brackets

I am working in TeXworks and I would like to use [ ] , but when i use \right] , it does not work. What should I do in this regards?when I use just ], there is no space between 2 and ],
how should I do it?

for example I have $x = [2, 2]$.

Comment: This is the right way to type, as you are doing: `$x=[2,2]$`. If you use `\right` you must use also `\left` before.

Comment: If it is one side , for exapmle $[2, \infty)$ what should I do?

Comment: Do exactly as you wrote. TeX will insert blank spaces if necessary.

Comment: I do not see any reason for using `\right` in the expression `$x=[2,2]$`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use `\right]`, as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$x=[2,2]$ $x=\left[2,2\right]$

$x=[2,\infty)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For denoting a half open interval, the notation with the parenthesis is the most common. If you instead prefer the reverse bracket, which you shouldn't do, use `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`:

```
$\mathopen]a,b]$
$[a,b\mathclose[$
$\mathopen]a,b\mathclose[$
```

You may have found that `\right` is to be used in the second case, but you have to remember that `\right` needs a matching `\left` before it.